# Show div after individual image loads

Tags: jquery, image, html, load, show

Lets say I have this kind of set of images:

```
<div class="image"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="" />image1</div>
<div class="image"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />image2</div>
<div class="image"><img src="image3.jpg" alt="" />image3</div>
```

(note that the `div`s would be initially hidden)

What I want is that, after an individual `<image>` has loaded, `.show();` the `div.image` surrounding it.

I would think this would be easy to do but I have searched all over the internet and so far they've been about doing something after all images have loaded instead of individual images.

Is this even possible to do?

Edit:
It was later on changed so that there's also link around the image
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/qwtWZ/6/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<div class="image"><img src="http://acupuncture.celeboutfit.com/images/img/IMG_5400m-1.jpg" alt="" />image1</div>
<div class="image"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />image2</div>
<div class="image"><img src="image3.jpg" alt="" />image3</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.image").hide();
    $("div.image").find("img").load(function(){
        $(this).closest("div.image").show(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/qwtWZ/6/

Comment: i didnt think it all the way through.. lets say i want to add link around the image.. http://jsfiddle.net/qwtWZ/ in this case .parent doesnt quite work.. i did try like.. .parent('.image') but didnt work

Comment: i swear that i tried to use closest too but it just didnt work.. well.. this is why i asked about it.. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".image img").load(function()
{
    $(this).closest(".image").show();
});
```

**Edit:**  Updated to allow for images that are descendants, but not necessarily children.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').load(function(){
    $(this).parent().show();
  });
});
```

should work just fine !

Answer (score 1):

You could load the images using jQuery like so

```
$("#img1").load('image1.jpg',function(){ $("#img1").show(); });
$("#img2").load('image2.jpg',function(){ $("#img2").show(); });
$("#img3").load('image3.jpg',function(){ $("#img3").show(); });
```

Where you give the above IDs to your divs. The function in the load() function is called when the resource has finished loading.

See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for the function reference.

Comment: is there easier way so that you could just point it into ".image img" ? as in: if ('.image img') is loaded -> $('.image').show(); ..individually of course..

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to prevent a FOUC but I didn't want to load awesome but heavy jQuery right at the top of my page so I wrote this utility script. In my example the parent container of the image is hidden until the image has been loaded. Works for me.

```js
(function() {

  function getArrayFromNodeList(list) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(list);
  }

  function ready() {
    var imageContent = document.querySelectorAll('.hero, .key-features__feature'),
      contentArray = getArrayFromNodeList(imageContent);

    contentArray.forEach(function(content) {
      var images = getArrayFromNodeList(content.querySelectorAll('img'));

      images.forEach(function(img) {
        img.onload = function() {
          console.log('img loaded');
          content.style.display = 'block';
        };
      });
    });
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

}());
```

```css
.hero,
.keyfeatures__feature {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Example of one piece of content -->
<article class="hero">
  <!-- This is the image I want to make sure has loaded -->
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/978/400/animals/grayscale" alt="">

  <!-- other HTML content -->
</article>
<!-- /hero -->

<!-- Example of another piece of content -->
<article class="key-features">
  <div class="key-features__feature">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/320/animals/grayscale" alt="">
  </div>
  <!-- /key-features__feature -->

  <div class="key-features__feature">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/320/animals/grayscale" alt="">
  </div>
  <!-- /key-features__feature -->
</article>
<!-- /key-features 6-6 -->
```